# Error while accepting inputs from command line in python

Tags: python, list, command-line

I tried to take an input from the command line by passing a file and storing it in an array.
I know my input is two words separated by white space, so I tried

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
   a=[]

   a=line.split() #to split the 2 words separated by white space into 2 list elements 

   print a # just to debug my code

   edges(a[0], a[1])  #calling the function edges
```

To this I m getting an error as:-

```
  edges(a[0], a[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone suggest what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: What is the `print a` printing?

Comment: What's `edges()` doing? Is it expecting a list input? If you've printed `a` and verified it has two elements, then that's not the problem.

Comment: @Brian This function takes the first passed element and stores it as a dictionary value and second element as a dictionary key

Comment: Might be helpful to show the `edges` function. I suspect that `edges` might be expecting something like `edges(a)` and references `a[0]` and `a[1]` internally, causing the `IndexError`. Does `print a[1]` also cause an `IndexError`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the index into which you are inputting the word. This will keep the list/array from overflowing and causing "index out of bounds" error.

**EDIT**
I see you are trying to store the first element as the key and then value. Please use a counter such as 'k' and 'v' to keep track and avoid overflows.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Yes the counter helped me debug the problem , thank you !